# How to use Visual Studio 2017 to develop an Angular 4 with an empty .NET framework, not using any C# codes to run anything?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I've found so many solutions from Google about how to make an Angular 2 application work in Visual Studio, but what I'd really like to do is to develop an application in Angular 4 and also NOT using C#. Given the convenience of Visual Studio in managing a project, I'm trying to use it as the tool to develop the Angular 4 application. But here comes the problem, I was not able to find any solution that's NOT using C# (would like to create an empty .NET framework instead of the core one) and also letting me to have an Angular **4** application successfully inject into the project that runs properly. I've tried stuffs like editing the base path in the `index.html` file but it stuck in displaying "Loading..." on the page.

How do I use VS (2017) to develop an Angular 4 application only using the .NET framework to help building up the environment to let VS start the server but not using any C# codes to build the application itself?

Please help with my noobness in Angular 4 and/or VS, I'm very new to both.

Comment: Do you mean https://code.visualstudio.com/ ?? I don't understand, you don't need anything to make it work, just execute ng init and open the files generated with visual studio code

Comment: I mean VS 2017, the local program. I'll try the ng init later to see if it's what I want. Thanks!

Comment: checkout this in order to use commands & angular 4 https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

Comment: @Marc Pérez It doesn't tell me how to develop the thing in VS though. :(

Comment: @Marc Pérez I just tried the ng init in the directory with the angular project and it tells me the command is invalid.

Comment: Hello Jenny, not sure if you came across this in google but this is what I have used to bootstrap Angular 4 Apps to be managed in Visual Studio   https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

Comment: Please, follow the steps you will find in the github page, one you followed that, open the visual studio code and open the angulars project folder

Answer (score 0):

Found a similar question -
[Running Visual Studio 2017 with Angular 4 and Angular CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530354/running-visual-studio-2017-with-angular-4-and-angular-cli#)

Heres the latest update:
UPDATE (2017-08-17)
Visual Studio 2017 15.3 now has the Angular template built in as a regular Web Application .NET Core project template. React and React/Redux templates are included too. You must choose ASP.NET Core 2.0 in the New ASP.NET Core Application dialog in order to see the templates as a choice. If you choose 1.1 or lower, the templates will not show in the list of options.