# Angular 5 Universal (SSR) with dotnet core not working with i18n angular tools on Staging server

Tags: angular-ui-router, internationalization, angular-universal, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to make the Angular Project Template with dotnet core running with the I18n Angular tool. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio)

Here is what I have in my startup class

```
app.Map("/fr", fr =>
{
    fr.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
        {
            options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/fr/main.bundle.js";
            options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
                ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr2:fr")
                : null;
            options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "serve:fr");
        }
    });
});


app.Map("/en", en =>
{
    en.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
        // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

        spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

        spa.UseSpaPrerendering(options =>
        {
            options.BootModulePath = $"{spa.Options.SourcePath}/dist-server/en/main.bundle.js";
            options.BootModuleBuilder = env.IsDevelopment()
                ? new AngularCliBuilder(npmScript: "build:ssr2:en")
                : null;
            options.ExcludeUrls = new[] { "/sockjs-node" };
        });

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "serve:en");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my build command

```
"build:ssr2:en":           "npm run buildssr-i1n8-en-browser && npm run buildssr-i1n8-en-server",
"buildssr-i1n8-en-browser":"ng build --aot --locale=en --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.en.xlf --base-href=/en/ --deploy-url=/en/ --output-path=dist/en ",
"buildssr-i1n8-en-server": "ng build --aot --locale=en --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.en.xlf --output-path=dist-server/en --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",

"build:ssr2:fr":           "npm run buildssr-i1n8-fr-browser && npm run buildssr-i1n8-fr-server",
"buildssr-i1n8-fr-browser":"ng build --aot --locale=fr --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf --base-href=/fr/ --deploy-url=/fr/ --output-path=dist/fr",
"buildssr-i1n8-fr-server": "ng build --aot --locale=fr --i18n-file src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf --output-path=dist-server/fr --app=ssr --output-hashing=media",

"serve:fr":                "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf --locale=fr --i18n-format=xlf --base-href=/fr/ ",
"serve:en":                "ng serve --aot --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.en.xlf --locale=en --i18n-format=xlf --base-href=/en/ ",
```

When I'm runing it in IIS Express from visual studio, and both languages works 
http://localhost:59508/en/ Working

For French 
http://localhost:59508/fr/ Working

On the production server, nothing work, even if I only put English Mapping.
I got this error

> An unhandled exception has occurred: The SPA default page middleware
>   could not return the default page '/index.html' because it was not
>   found, and no other middleware handled the request. Your application
>   is running in Production mode, so make sure it has been published, or
>   that you have built your SPA manually. Alternatively you may wish to
>   switch to the Development environment.

The file is well generated in dist/fr , dist/en and dist-server/fr, dist-server/en

Any Idea why it doesn't work on my production server ?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Wow, it's was simple as add that in my startup class

spa.Options.DefaultPage = $"/en/index.html"; // for English

spa.Options.DefaultPage = $"/fr/index.html"; // for French

Answer (score 3):

To complete **Jean-Francois** question these 2 settings worked for me

First:

```
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
  spa.Options.DefaultPage = $"/hr/index.html"; // Default language to use
});
```

Second:

```
app.Map("/en", en =>
{
  en.UseSpa(spa =>
  {
      spa.Options.DefaultPage = $"/en/index.html";
  });
});

app.Map("/hr", hr =>
{
  hr.UseSpa(spa =>
    {
        spa.Options.DefaultPage = $"/hr/index.html";
    });
});
```

First one was better becouse it automatically redirects to default language set in angular.json file and its shorter :P. Example uses angular 7 with built options like said above. Trick is to set the baseHref to folder location.

Comment: In "first", aren't you just overwriting the `spa.Options.DefaultPage` field? So `spa.Options.DefaultPage = $"/en/index.html";` has no effect.

Comment: @Jeppe i thought so but it works maybe someone from the aspnet team can explain :)

Comment: Does it not work if you remove the first line? You can see the setter here: [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Middleware/SpaServices.Extensions/src/SpaOptions.cs#L41)

Comment: Yea actually it and it sets the default as it states :) changing the answer

Comment: Can you explain how solution 1 works? Doesn't it map all routes to `/hr/index.html`?

Comment: @Jeppe actually it just serves default version if nothing is specified if you want en version you navigate to localhost:5000/en/

Comment: Dživo Jelić Thank you!!!