# Is it possible to host two React apps in same .Net project?

Tags: reactjs, .net, hosting

I am trying to host two React ClientApp projects in the same .Net project. The purpose of this action is to have both apps have the same origin, so they share the same browser session, and server session, this helps me in some business logic.

I have found a post explaining the steps but it was unuseful for my case. Here's the link:
[How to host multiple React SPA apps on a single ASP.NET Core site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64013772/how-to-host-multiple-react-spa-apps-on-a-single-asp-net-core-site)

However, I don't need to change the original app, which is named ClientApp, to another path. I just need to host the second app to a new branch instead, for example:

- First App remains hosted at '/'.
- Second App hosted at '/branch'.

Any idea on how to modify to code in the link above to meet my requirements?